# Destroy session instead of clearing it in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, session

I tried looking for the place where Laravel destroys the session in the default Auth scaffolding, but I can't find it. I **CAN** however find the place where it gets **cleared**. The default `logout()` function in AuthenticateUsers.php:

```
/**
 * Log the user out of the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    return $this->loggedOut($request) ?: redirect('/');
}
```

`$this->guard()->logout();` points to StatefulGuard.php:

```
/**
 * Log the user out of the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function logout();
```

`$request->session()->invalidate();` points to the `invalidate()` function in Store.php, which points to `flush()` also in Store.php. This function however only clears the session, it doesn't destroy it:

```
/**
 * Remove all of the items from the session.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function flush()
{
    $this->attributes = [];
}
```

So my question here is: **Does Laravel even destroy the session in the default Auth scaffolding?** If it does: where does it do this? I can absolutely not find it and I've been searching for hours.

p.s. don't mark this as a duplicate because using Session::flush() is not an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I actually just found it. Turns out I was blind this whole time.

The `invalidate()` function in Store.php **returns** `$this->migrate(true)`. This function uses the default PHP SessionHandlerInterface to destroy the session:

```
/**
 * Generate a new session ID for the session.
 *
 * @param  bool  $destroy
 * @return bool
 */
public function migrate($destroy = false)
{
    if ($destroy) {
        $this->handler->destroy($this->getId());
    }

    $this->setExists(false);

    $this->setId($this->generateSessionId());

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use destroy() method of session to destroy it completely try using,

```
$request->session()->destroy();
```

Put this to your logout method or after the call of that method so that it gets destroy after you logout from the system.

Comment: This means I would have to override logout(), which wasn't my question.